# Weighted sum vs Weighted overlay

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, weighted-overlay, suitability-analysis

I´m working on a suitability analysis for which I´m doing a sensitivity analysis.

When I modify the weights for this analysis I have values with decimals, so I can´t use "weighted overlay" tool.

Can I use "weighted sum" tool (considering that the weights I use sum 1)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [Weighted Sum](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/weighted-sum.htm) since your weights are decimals and as long as the total equals to 1, so there is no problem.

I will quote from the help above:

> A useful way to add several rasters together is to input multiple
>   rasters and set all **weights equal to 1**.
>
> Input rasters can be **integer** or **floating point**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Esri's [Weighted Sum](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/weighted-sum.htm) page provide the following usage details:

[image]

> A useful way to add several rasters together is to input multiple rasters and set all weights equal to 1.
>
> Input rasters can be integer or floating point.
>
> The weight values can be any positive or negative decimal value. It is not restricted to a relative percentage nor does it need to be equal to 1.0.
>
> The weight will be applied to the specified field for the input raster. Fields can be of type short or long integer, double or float.
>
> By default, this tool will take advantage of multi-core processors. The maximum number of cores that can be utilized is limited to four.
>
> If you want the tool to use fewer cores, use the parallelProcessingFactor environment setting.